# get the number of weeks (rows) in a month from moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'd like to get the number of calendar rows (weeks) in any month using momentjs

For example:

This would be `5`

[image]

and this would be `6`

[image]

Heres what I have to work with:

I have the month, start of month, and end of month as a moment items

```
const month; // (month moment obj)
const start = moment(month).startOf('month');
const end = moment(month).endOf('month');
```

Heres what I've tried so far (with no luck)

```
const weeks = end.diff(start, 'week'); // always gives 4
const weeks = moment.duration(end - start).weeks() + 1; // always gives 5
```

I really would prefer to use Moment.js for simplicity and accuracy. I've seen some pure JS answers on here but none of them are truly reliable.

Comment: While this is not the direct answer, maybe someone will benefit from it. There is a library called 'date-fns' which has a variety of functions that cover almost all you can think of covering date and time: https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/getWeeksInMonth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a curious problem. Edited new solution: count the days of the first week (row one), then the next weeks (middle rows), if there are pending days add another row:

Taking into account that week starts on Monday with 'isoWeekDay()'.

As of October 9th 2019:

```
let now = moment('9/oct/2019');
// First row
let firstWeekDays = 7 - now.startOf('month').isoWeekday() + 1;
let rows = 1
rest = now.daysInMonth() - firstWeekDays;
// Middle rows
let middleRows = Math.floor(rest/7);
rows = rows + middleRows;
rest = rest - (middleRows * 7);
// Last row?
if (rest > 0) {
    rows = rows + 1;
}
console.log(rows); // 5
```

Comment: actually there is an issue with january's, its returning `-47`

Comment: I am looking for a better one, January and December are conflictive.

Comment: not working in january 2021 , february 2021

Comment: Needs to take care of the starting day of the week...

Answer (score 0):

You should take in consideration also the offsets.

```
function weeksOfMonth (input = moment()) {
  const startMonth = input.clone().startOf('month');
  const startWeek = startMonth.clone().startOf('isoWeek');
  const startOffset = startMonth.diff(startWeek, 'days'); 
  
  const endMonth = input.clone().endOf('month');
  const endWeek = endMonth.clone().endOf('isoWeek');
  const endOffset = endWeek.diff(endMonth, 'days'); 

  return Math.ceil((endMonth.diff(startMonth, 'days') + startOffset + endOffset) / 7);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably this is not the best way to do it, but at least it gives the correct answer.

```
function getWeeksInMonth(date: Moment | null) {
    if (!date) {
        return 0;
    }

    let weeksInMonth = 0;
    const firstMonthDate = date.clone().startOf('month');
    const lastMonthDate = firstMonthDate.clone().endOf('month');
    const currentWeekFirstDate = firstMonthDate.clone().startOf('week');

    while (lastMonthDate.isAfter(currentWeekFirstDate)) {
        weeksInMonth++;
        currentWeekFirstDate.add(1, 'week');
    }

    return weeksInMonth;
}
```